# how to obtain the position of an element in an array and in a cycle omit that element?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I´m doing a series of mathematical operations in my web application, and I would like to obtain something like the following:

Given an array of N elements, for example `[1,2,3]`, print on the screen another array with the same number of elements where each position is the multiplication of all elements of the array except the position to be calculated.

The result examples:

`[1,2,3]` has to print: `[6,3,2]`

`[5,2,3,2,4]` has to print: `[48,120,80, 120, 60]`

Comment: show your code what u have tried and where are you not getting output @Eduardo Quiñonez

Comment: "_where each position is the multiplication of all elements_ "of all elements in the array or all elements before that given element? - What is your expected output for the array `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Something like this:
[1,2,3] has to print: [6,3,2]
[5,2,3,2,4] has to print: [48,120,80, 60]

Comment: Your second example has 5 elements in the input and 4 in the output... is that a typo?

Comment: Dumb questions: For `[1,2,3] => [6,3,2]` - Q: what is the "position to be calculated"?  Q: Where does it come from (user input?  Other?)  Q What exactly is getting multiplied?  Q: Why does the 1st example have 3 and 3 elements ... but the second example 5 ad 4 elements?  Shouldn't it be 3 and 2, and 4 and 3?  I don't understand "the problem".

Comment: @paulsm4 sorry, I did omit the 120 value, [1,2,3] has to print: [6,3,2]  and [5,2,3,2,4] has to print: [48,120,80,120, 60]

we have to create an array with the same number of elements where each position is the multiplication of all elements of the array except the position to be calculated. 

the operation in the array of 1,2,3 is the follow: in the new array, in the first position we have to multiplicate 2*3, because we have to omit the number of the position wich is calculate, in this case we omit 1, the second operation is: 1*3 because we omit the second position of the first array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No special array manipulations (slicing/splicing), just super simple math.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Fk8XB))

```
$array = [5,2,3,2,4];

foreach ($array as $val) {
    $result[] = array_product($array) / $val;
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 48,
  1 => 120,
  2 => 80,
  3 => 120,
  4 => 60,
)
```

You can cache `array_product($array)` before the loop for greater efficiency. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/iBkDm)  This is effectively the same logic as Nick's answer, I just find it easier to read using language construct versus functional programming.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array_product()` to get the product of all values in your array, and then use `array_map()` to divide by each value given to "remove" that from the overall product.

```
$arr =  [1, 2, 3];

$product = array_product($arr);
$res = array_map(function ($v) use ($product) {
  return $product == 0 ? 0 : $product/$v;
}, $arr);

print_r($res);
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 3 [2] => 2 )
```

*Other cases:*

`[5, 2, 3, 2, 4]` gives `[48, 120, 80, 120, 60]`

Answer (score 1):

A normal for loop gives you access to the current index. Within each iteration of the loop you can use array_slice to make a copy and array_splice to remove one element. Then array_reduce with a suitable callback to multiply the remaining values.

```
function reduce_to_products_without_value_at_index( $initial_array ) {
  $num_elements = count( $initial_array );
  $product_array = [];

  for ( $index = 0; $index < $num_elements; $index++ ) {
    $array_copy = array_slice( $initial_array, 0 );
    array_splice( $array_copy, $index, 1 );
    $product = array_reduce( $array_copy, function( $carry, $item ) {
      return $carry * $item;
    }, 1 );
    $product_array[$index] = $product;
  }

  print_r( $product_array );
}

reduce_to_products_without_value_at_index( [1,2,3] );
reduce_to_products_without_value_at_index( [5,2,3,2,4] );
```